# How to decide on Combination formula for "How many bit strings of length 25 have exactly 7 1s" - C(25, 18) or C(25, 7)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

If I choose 7 different places for all my 1's to go that would C(25, 7) but alternatively if I want to think of it in terms of 18 different places for all my 0's to go that would be C(25, 18). A bit string of length 25 which has exactly 7 1s is determined by the positions of the 7 1s in the string (or equivalently the 18 positions of the 0s). So which is it?

Comment: Have you checked whether they give the same result or not ? And whether if they give the same result, whether it is just a coincidence ?

Comment: To amplify the comment of @trueblueanil, using factorials, write out the formulas for $\binom{25}{7}$ and for $\binom{25}{18}$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I tried out what the comments were mentioning and realized that it ends up being the same and it is not a coincidence. Then through searching some more, discovered there's a mathematical rule that if n and r be nonnegative integers with r ≤ n, then C(n, r) = C(n, n − r).

Comment: Notice that the number of bit strings of length $25$ with exactly seven ones is equal to the number of bit strings of length $25$ with exactly $18$ zeros since each element of a bit string is either a zero or a one.